# Make ModalBottomSheetLayout always Expanded

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using `ModalBottomSheetLayout` in Jetpack Compose. Whenever it is shown with `modalBottomSheetState.show()`, it shows `HalfExpanded` or `Expanded` depending on the height of its content. This is from the source code:

```
val anchors = if (sheetHeight < fullHeight / 2) {
        mapOf(
            fullHeight to Hidden,
            fullHeight - sheetHeight to Expanded
        )
    } else {
        mapOf(
            fullHeight to Hidden,
            fullHeight / 2 to HalfExpanded,
            max(0f, fullHeight - sheetHeight) to Expanded
        )
    }
    Modifier.swipeable(
        state = sheetState,
        anchors = anchors,
        orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
        enabled = sheetState.currentValue != Hidden,
        resistance = null
    )
```

Then `show()` works like here:

```
 internal val isHalfExpandedEnabled: Boolean
    get() = anchors.values.contains(HalfExpanded)

/**
 * Show the bottom sheet with animation and suspend until it's shown. If half expand is
 * enabled, the bottom sheet will be half expanded. Otherwise it will be fully expanded.
 *
 * @throws [CancellationException] if the animation is interrupted
 */
suspend fun show() {
    val targetValue =
        if (isHalfExpandedEnabled) HalfExpanded
        else Expanded
    animateTo(targetValue = targetValue)
}
```

I wonder if we can set it to always `Expanded` somehow

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use:

```
scope.launch { state.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded) }
```

instead of

```
scope.launch { state.show() }
```

Starting with compose **`1.2`** you can use the **`skipHalfExpanded`** attribute:

> **skipHalfExpanded** : If true, the sheet will always expand to the Expanded state and move to the Hidden state when hiding the sheet, either programmatically or by user interaction

Something like:

```
var skipHalfExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
val state = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
    skipHalfExpanded = skipHalfExpanded
)
```

Answer (score 14):

use:

```kotlin
bottomSheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
```

to show expanded sheet

use `confirmStateChange`:

```
 val bottomSheetState =
        rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden, confirmStateChange = {
            it != ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded
        })
```

to avoid sheet halfexpanded

Comment: Nice, exactly what I needed to avoid the HalfExpanded state

Answer (score 10):

Use skipHalfExpanded

```
val bottomSheetStatus =
    rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
        skipHalfExpanded = true,
    )
```

Comment: Just to make it clear: this approach works only for Compose 1.2 or above which is currently on alpha stage. For version 1.1 or below, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69232259/4398784 is a good approach.